# Can I edit a html file directly on Github (on my browser, not desktop)?

Tags: github

If yes, how can I do that? Do I have to do a 'branch' first?
I didn't find how to do it on Google.

Can someone please help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it on GitHub itself.

1. In your repository, browse to the file you want to edit
2. In the upper right corner of the file view, click  to open the file editor.

[image]

3. On the Edit file tab, make any changes you need to the file. I am going to add a new paragraph as "new paragraph".

[image]

4. Then commit the changes. At the bottom of the page, type a short, meaningful commit message that describes the change you made to the file. You can create a new branch and commit the changes as follows simultaneously as follows. I add the branch name as "new-branch".

[image]

5. Next, open a pull request to merge your changes to the main branch.

[image]

6. Finally you can merge the changes from your branch to the main branch.

[image]

7. Now you can view the updated file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Pawara!! Sounds stupid, but I kept clicking on 'update index.html' instead of index.html to start editing it.

Comment: I do understand @Severin. Sometimes you may need a little help from outside to resolve very small issues. I can remember even I have faced simillar situations. I am happy that I could help you.